# Spring+Oracle+JPA+H2 ORA-00972: identifier is too long

Tags: oracle11g, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring boot + H2 + Oracle + JPA.

When I use H2 everything works fine. Like insert and retrieve operations work fine. But when I put below configuration to use Oracle it start throwing exception regardless what operation I do with Oracle.

```
database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
datasource:
url: "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE"
username: root
password: root
driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

I created a simple Test class with only id and name and tried to save it with Oracle and it works fine even with Oracle. But my old beans are not working with Oracle.

Below is my new Test.java that works in both Oracle and H2.

```
Test.java     
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_GEN")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_GEN", sequenceName = "TEST_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
private long id;
private String name;
```

One of my old class that works fine with H2 but not with Oracle.

```
 Abc.java
 @Entity
 @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
 public class SampleRule 
 {

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
@RestResource(exported = false)
private Test test;
```

Even Abc.java class is not getting created in Oracle but in H2.

---

1. Why few tables are not created using the import script? But they got created when I use H2 but with Oracle they are not.
2. When to use @Table and @Column annotation? If I use Oracle then I need to use these annotation? .Because even without these annotations my Test.java class is being created and saved into Oracle database. Also I am able to retrieve it. But other tables throws error when I try to retrieve it.

Thanks!

Comment: "*identifier is too long*" is pretty clear. You can't have identifiers longer than 30 characters in Oracle. Apparently JPA tries to create a table with a longer name. Print the SQL that is created by your obfuscation layer to find the offending statement

Comment: You could also include at least some of the exception stack, that might narrow it down a bit.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

I am not really getting when to use @ Column annotations and when to not. Because my Test class is not having any @ Column but still it is created in Oracle and able to retrieve it. 

org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: drop table my_test_class cascade constraints
org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : ORA-00972: identifier is too long

 org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000388: Unsuccessful: INSERT INTO

Comment: Thanks guys I found the solution. I put the @Table(name = "table_name") as my class name was more than 30 characters and then I put the @Table name lesser than 30 characters and it worked in Oracle. 
Thanks Once Again.